# SQL Server: Apply different multipliers by date

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that records sales and I want a report on how much tax was paid on each item. The basic rule is all sales before April 1st had a .52% tax, all sales after that date will have a 0.5% tax.

I'm trying to get this using the following query

```
select ItemCode,
    sum(Quantity) QuantitySold,
    WhsCode as Store,
    case when (docdate < '20170401') then sum(Quantity * .0052) else sum(Quantity * .005) end as Tax
from SalesTable
group by whscode,
    itemcode
```

However I get a

> DocDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in
>   either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

error if I run it as is. Adding DocDate to the group by clause creates a mess of duplicates (On one example I went from 185 rows to 1508 rows).

Does SQL simply not allow you to use `WHEN` statements whose conditional is not included in the Group clause or should I be using something else?

Comment: It's weird that you're applying the tax to the `quantity` instead of a sales total of `quantity*price`. I'm not saying it's wrong, it just seems strange to see it written that way.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I got it mixed up with a different flat per-item tax -- It should be on the price, not the quantity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is because you are using docdate directly without adding it to the group by clause.

I think this is what you want:

```
select ItemCode,
    sum(Quantity) QuantitySold,
    WhsCode as Store,
    sum(price * case when docdate < '20170401' then 0.0052 else 0.005 end) as Tax
from SalesTable
group by whscode,
    itemcode
```